# Unix "script" command unstoppable by tracked user

Tags: security, unix, logging, terminal

I would like to track everything in a term (commands typed, etc) so I tried "script" which does everything I need except that I don't want the user currently connected (and logged via script) to exit and stop the sniffing.

Is there any good way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no.  You could `exec script` which would keep them from going back to a shell, **but**, once they are inside `script`, all the user has to do is run `script` inside `script`, cause the mayhem, and then exit both.  This covers their tracks.